# Download your files from your dedicated server to synology

Tags: ssh, ftp, rsync, synchronization

I'm trying to write a program/script to download files from my dedicated server (CPanel) to my Local synology.  Ideally, I would like to sync it, but for now I'd rather just download.  I found this PHP sync script which seemed interesting:

https://github.com/outlandishideas/sync

After investigating tho, the script is not quite able to handle large amounts of data (Many GB) over HTTP.  Are there any recommendations on a package that might exist for Synology servers I can use to sync my FTP/SSh Dedicated server to my local Synology?  Sort of like a GoodSync or [FTPBox](http://ftpbox.org/) (Windows) for synology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use rsync? It's very reliable, secure, able to handle large amounts of data efficiently and is available on pretty much any platform, including Synology.

You mention you have SSH access to your dedicated server, so setting this up should be easy. There are plenty of issues with transferring large amounts of data over HTTP and I think you'll be spending more time fixing those than getting rsync to work.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I guess I want to, but I'm a PHP guy, and I can't find any good documentation on how to set it up.  Do I need a cronjob to run it?

Comment: The documentation on this is poor too, but sounds promising:  [https://github.com/crazy-max/ftp-sync](https://github.com/crazy-max/ftp-sync)

Comment: Hey, I started as a PHP guy too :). Avoid FTP, it's insecure and obsolete. Learning SSH and related tools like rsync is worth your time. Here's a tutorial on rsync:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps. Get it working manually first. Then set up a passwordless SSH keypair for authentication. Finally add the rsync command to cron and you're done.